# Key binding with an argument

Tags: key-bindings, shell, minibuffer, shell-command

Say I have a shell command `foo` that I want to bind to a key. I could do for example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") (lambda () (interactive) (shell-command "foo")))
```

I would like to be able to pass an argument to `foo`. An argument will be the name of a file in the current directory, so I would like to take an advantage of shell auto-complete. The preferable behavior would be for `C-c f` to open shell in the minibuffer with `foo` already entered so that I can just add the filename and hit `RET`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: As a hint — start with the manual for the `(interactive)` form

Comment: If this question is answered then please consider accepting the answer. This is still on the unanswered list. Thx.

Answer (score 7):

As you seem to have already noticed, a function need the `interactive` form before it can be bound to a key.  `interactive` doesn't just tell Emacs the function is a command, it is also tells Emacs where to get the functions arguments from.  From `C-h f interactive`:

> Specify a way of parsing arguments for interactive use of a function.
>   For example, write
>    (defun foo (arg buf) "Doc string" (interactive "P\nbbuffer: ") .... )
>    to make ARG be the raw prefix argument, and set BUF to an existing buffer,
>    when ‘foo’ is called as a command.

A typical case is `(interactive c)` where `c` is a single-letter string describe the type of argument you expect.  "f" means "existing file".

An example function would then be

```
(defun test-command (file)
  (interactive "f")
  (message file))
```

Or to run a shell command `foo` on a file:

```
(defun foo-file (file)
  (interactive "f")
  (shell-command (format "foo %s" (shell-quote-argument file))))
```

Notice that we wrap the file name with `shell-quote-argument` which will quote the file name so that it's safer to call shell commands on it in case your file names have spaces or special shell characters. Safety First. (thanks @YoungFrog for the suggestion)

Bind it to a key and call it.  Emacs will prompt you for a file name in the usual way, using whatever kind of completion you have set up, and then pass the name (as a string) into the function as `file`.

Comment: You want to add a bit of `quote-shell-argument` in there, for the cases where the file name has quotes, spaces, newlines or other weird characters.

Comment: Good idea. Safety first.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `foo-file` seems to add quotation marks around the file path and `foo` doesn't recognize it.

Comment: The quotes are added by `shell-quote-argument`. The shell should be eating them.

Comment: I see, for some reason my shell doesn't eat them. If I remove `shell-quote-argument` it does work... except when there are spaces in the path of the file.

Comment: BTW, the way this works now the full path is passed as an argument to `foo`. Would it be possible to pass only the filename?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: My `explicit-shell-file-name` and `ESHELL` are nil, but `shell-file-name` is `/bin/bash` so I guess it's bash.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's going on. Maybe another question is in order?