# Interactive lambda functions

Tags: key-bindings, evil, commands, interactive, defun

How do I create interactive lambda functions?

```
(use-package general
  :ensure t
  :config
  (general-evil-setup t)
  ;;(setq general-default-keymaps 'evil-normal-state-map)

  (general-define-key
   :states '(normal motion emacs)
   :prefix "SPC"
   "l"  '(:ignore t :which-key "Workspace")
   "lc" '(perspeen-create-ws :which-key "Create workspace")
   "l1" '((lambda () (interactive) (perspeen-goto-ws 1)) :which-key "Workspace 1")
   "l2" '((lambda () (interactive) (perspeen-goto-ws 2)) :which-key "Workspace 2")

   )
)
```

This works but isn't there a less vebose way?

I also tired `funcall` and `call-interactively`

```
"l1" '((funcall perspeen-goto-ws '1) :which-key "Workspace 1")
```

But that doesn't seem to work

Another idea was to expand a macro but that also doesn't seem to work

```
(defmacro goto-ws (idx)
  (lambda () (interactive) (perspeen-goto-ws idx)))

"l2" '((expand-macro '(goto-ws 2)) :which-key "Workspace 2")
```

Comment: 0. Your question is unclear.
1. Please try to remove everything from your question that is not strictly related. For example, if the question does not depend on `use-package` or on binding keys, remove such stuff.
2. Your macro does nothing, pretty much. A macro should generate code that then gets evaluated.
3. *See the Elisp manual, node [Using Interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html), to learn about `interactive`.*

Comment: I found the solution I was looking for here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17617/key-binding-with-an-argument